# Have JIRA send mails to watchers on commit from Stash on a ticket

Tags: git, email, jira, bitbucket-server

Our workflow is as follows:

- Someone opens ticket in JIRA (ABC-123)
- Developer commits with commit message ("Do the thing, relates to ABC-123")
- Developer pushes to Stash server
- Commit will show on JIRA (and when viewed on Stash, ticket will linked to JIRA).

  - Note: I'm not sure if the above workflow is implemented by us, a plugin, or out of box by JIRA/Stash

My question is, Is there any event that is or can be fired in Jira that can be used for triggering email notification?

So if Alice, Bob and Charlie watch ABC-123, they should get an email about the commit by our Developer.

I have scourged the official documentation from Atlassian [some](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme) [examples](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/137670/trigger-an-email-to-jira-issue-watchers-on-a-changeset-commit), and various plugins, but didn't seem to find anything.

Comment: what about a git hook?

Comment: What about a git hook? It seems silly that the git hook would have to parse the commit message to get the ticket, then ask JIRA for the watch list, then send a mail. This seems like a relatively common case for a ticket manager / git host. Nevertheless, if you have a solution involving a git hook, feel free to post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the work flow you use requires [Git Integration Plugin for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xiplink.jira.git.jira_git_plugin) or JIRA DVCS Connector (if you are using Bitbucket or Github) so I assume you use that.

An alternative is to use the [JIRA REST API](http://maxoberberger.net/blog/2014/02/git-hook-for-jira-rest-api/) to handle your tickets with git hooks - this should trigger the notifications on the JIRA tickets, since it's basically a shortcut that handles your JIRA tickets directly from commit messages - it's same as if you did it manually.

Assuming you have Git Integration Plugin for Jira, to make your notifications work you will have to edit the [Notification Scheme](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme) - you will have to setup the project permissions - specifically **View Development Tools** permission must be granted to **Users > Group > Project Roles** (read Setting Up Repositories on http://bigbrassband.com/documentation.html) in order to view the git related data on JIRA ticket.

You may also want to go through all settings in the plugin "Advanced setup" and check if any of this features is set to Disabled and enable it.

Comment: This answer got us the closest! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's something called the [Notification Assistant for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.notificationassistant). I'm pretty sure this is what my company uses to notify us of Github commits via the Hipchat application. Looks like there's a way to have it auto-generate emails for you too.

Take a look in the slideshow for it. Here's a  couple screenshots that make me think this is what you're looking for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of that plugin! Nice. It's not *quite* what we're looking for though, it's close. Sadly, I can only award the bounty to one answer, so have my +1 and gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the events within JIRA that can be notified from, other than "Generic Event" which I'm not sure when will be fired, perhaps using some of the other [smart commit](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages) tags could help achieve this goal?

For example, developers could prepend their commit messages with `ISSUE_KEY #comment` so their commit comment gets added as a comment to the JIRA issue. Then you could configure the "Issue Commented" event to notify the appropriate people.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jira admin access you may change all that relates to Jira notifications. At my previous company all Jira users will get notifications on a standard Jira group ... others that needs specific notifications will be added into different jira groups under Jira admin